# Secure place to save encryption keys

Tags: android, security, ssl, encryption, android-keystore

I've read about Keystore which is in fact `a repository of security certificates – either authorization certificates or public key certificates – used for instance in SSL encryption.(by Wikipedia)`.

Android developers use the Keystore to store their encryption keys in it, instead of 
embedding the encryption key inside the android application. That's supposed to solve the problem of a hacker which is decompile their app and get the encryption key the is used by the app.

Whenever you want access the data inside the Keystore you have to specify a password. What prevents the hacker from decompiling the app, extracting the Keystore's password, and then gathering the encryption key inside the Keystore?

Or maybe I got it all wrong?

Comment: That's interesting, someone?

Comment: Are you talking about the keystore you use to sign your application or are you trying to store secure data inside your app?

Comment: I understand that whenever I want to store an encryption private key in a secure way, I should store it in Keystore. Am I right?

Comment: Yeah, most of the time you would want to store it there.

Comment: "Android developers use Keystore usually for store their encryption key in it, instead of embed the encryption key inside the android application." Do you have a citation for this? I'm interested in reviewing the exact usage.

Comment: See [Unifying Key Store Access in ICS](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2012/03/unifying-key-store-access-in-ics.html) and [Using the ICS KeyChain API](http://nelenkov.blogspot.com/2011/11/using-ics-keychain-api.html).

Answer (score 2):

They are likely storing that key encrypted in the keystore itself. To access the key store, you will need some combination of the user's passcode for unlocking the android device and/or a device specific code such that only that device can decrypt the keystore.